# VHost & htaccess - 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I use **ISPConfig 3** to manage my domains/subdomains.

I added subdomain `parim.kristian.ee` which would redirect to `web/parim/` (*note: **web/** is my document root*).

ISPConfig generated such redirect to apache config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^parim.kristian.ee [NC]
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ /parim/$1  [L]
```

Now if i'll try to get static resources, such as http://parim.kristian.ee/images/1x1.gif, it serves fine, but when redirect is to codeigniter, it doesn't work.

Htaccess in `web/parim/` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    Options -Indexes

    #Handle CodeIgniter request
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 ./index.php
</IfModule>
```

**NOTE:** accessing the same folder via http://kristian.ee/parim/ works!

I s*ck at htaccess, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# To remove index.php from URL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /parim
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Or Simple remove RewriteBase /parim